# In git, how to merge a branch into another branch though only the changes and not the master merges

Tags: git, git-merge

I would like to merge the change sets from one branch into another branch.  For example, merge issues/bug1 into issues/bug5.  In issues/bugs branch a number of merges with master has occurred.  I would only want the changes associated with the issues/bug1 into issues/bug5 without the master merges.  Is that possible and how so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the branch issues/bug5 do:

`git rebase issues/bug1 -i`

Or

`git merge issues/bug1`